# Postman post request to Rails API strong params error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, postman

I have a controller that uses strong params with `require` and `permit`. When I'm testing this endpoint with postman, I keep getting something like:

```
undefined method `permit' for "{foo: [1,2,3], bar: 1}":String
```

I know this controller works fine when I make the post request through the UI, but testing with postman gives me this error each time. I'm sending my payload through raw as JSON(application/json) and the header with the corresponding content type too.

This is the body I'm passing thru:

```
{
    "foos": {"foo":[1,2,3], "bar": 2675}
}
```

[image]

```
  def foos_params
    params.require(:foos).permit(:foo, :bar)
  end
```

Comment: can you share the postman request/collection?

Comment: I think you are not passing the keys as strings. Make the request body: {"foo": [1,2,3], "bar": 1}

Comment: @stackjlei You need to pass the key for permit parameters. like user: {foo: [1,2,3],bar: 1}

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon please see edit above

Comment: @Sajin I did do that, please see edit

Comment: @Vishal I did do that see above

Comment: Make sure the body is selected `raw` with type `application/json` i.e. `content-type` should be `application/json`.

Comment: @kapilsdv like in the picture?

Comment: @stackjlei yes. Are you still getting the error?

Comment: @kapilsdv yes I am

Comment: post your strong parameter method on controller

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon done

Comment: ok...also the logs when you receive the request

Answer (score 2):

In Headers tab add `Content-Type: Application/json`[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,

with Postman input params:

key       : value

foos[foo] : [1,2,3] `# this is string:  JSON.stringify([1,2,3]) => "[1,2,3]"`

foos[bar] : 2675

In controller:

```
def foos_params
   params.require(:foos).permit(:foo, :bar)
end
```

But, we need convert string to array for `:foo`:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(foos_params[:foo]) # => [1, 2, 3]
```